# Apache POI: How to Retrieve Changed Rows in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Hey I'd like to know that is it possible to find only changed/updated Microsoft **Excel/Spreadsheet** rows using Apache POI in Java?

Its possible in C# and VB (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thc1eetk.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

> Each row in a data table has a **RowState** property that keeps track of the current state of that row using the values in the **DataRowState** enumeration. You can return changed rows from a dataset or data table by calling the GetChanges method of a **DataSet** or **DataTable**. You can verify changes exist prior to calling GetChanges by calling the **HasChanges** method of a dataset.

Comment: The aim of `apache poi` is working with `Microsoft Office` files while your link is about how to use `DataTable`s using `.NET`. So your question is a little bit like: Can I peel an apple using a knife? It is possible to eat an egg using a spoon. No, `apache poi` is not able using `System.Data.DataTable`.

Comment: I just provided details if Apache POI has these kinda methods or not.

Comment: Please state what Microsoft Office files are exactly meant. Access Database `*.mdb` or `*.accdb`? If so, then no, not possible using `apache poi`.

Comment: Microsoft Excel

Comment: Well, find only changed/updated Microsoft Excel rows. Rows changed/updated in comparison with which previous version of the file? There is a difference between a file containing data and a database application. The database application is able listening the changes of data as long as it runs and setting change flags to the data. The file stores data as they were the time it was saved. So for detecting changes we need a previos set of data from a  previous version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

To track changed rows, set up a map, with cell references (A1..whatever), obtained by [iterating over the cells](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) as keys and their [SHA digest](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#digestAsHex(java.lang.String)) as the value. Recalculate the hash and compare. If they differ, the cell has changed. If not, they're the same. Hope that helps...